# Collapsible hamburger on Navbar not working in bootstrap (offline mode)

Tags: bootstrap-4

Bootstrap Hamburger that appears on the navbar when you resize the window is not responding to a click. This is how I have it set up:

```
<script src="/static/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="/static/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/popper.min.js"></script>
```

This is my layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/bootstrap.min.css">

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Blog</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    
        <button class="navbar-toggler collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarColor02" aria-controls="navbarColor02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarColor02" style="">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{{url_for('core.index')}}">Home</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href=" {{url_for('core.about')}}">About</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Log Out</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Account</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Create Post</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Log In</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Register</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <script src="/static/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <div class="container">
        {% block content %}

        {% endblock %}
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is how it looks: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUDHM.jpg).

And this is what I expect it to look like: [working hamburger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6AFea.jpg).

The problem is that it doesn't respond to a click. How to fix this?
**Important note:** I'm trying to set it up **offline**.
With online links to css and js files, everything is working well.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's not clear from your question what is the problem. Could you edit it to clarify what exactly do you expect to happen, and what happens instead?

Comment: The Hamburger doesn't open as the picture shows. I will add a screenshot to describe the desired result. thanks

Comment: I've noticed that in your html there is a space where it shouldn't be: `data- toggle="collapse"` should be `data-toggle="collapse"`. Would it help if you remove the space?

Comment: My bad, error on pasting, it is without the space and I've fixed it now. Still not working